# PrevState typing in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a context to store an object for my dialog. I have a function which updates an array stored in the context based on prevState however, TypeScript doesn't like my prevState typing.

> Argument of type '(prevState: SourceOrganizationAccount[]) => SourceOrganizationAccount[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SourceOrganizationAccount[]'.
> Type '(prevState: SourceOrganizationAccount[]) => SourceOrganizationAccount[]' is missing the following properties from type 'SourceOrganizationAccount[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.

Here's my component with the function `handleCheckAccountDetailsClick`. It complains on this line `sourceOrganizationAccounts.setValue((prevState: SourceOrganizationAccount[]) => {`. What is wrong with that prevState?

```
import React from 'react';
import { getAccount } from 'utils';
import {
  SourceOrganizationAccount,
  useImportAccountsContext,
} from '../ImportAccountsContext';

export function ImportAccountsTable() {
  const { sourceOrganizationAccounts } = useImportAccountsContext();

  async function handleCheckAccountDetailsClick(account: SourceOrganizationAccount) {
    const accountDetailsRes = await getAccount();

    if (accountDetailsRes.success) {
      sourceOrganizationAccounts.setValue((prevState: SourceOrganizationAccount[]) => {
        const updatedArray = prevState.map(sourceOrganizationAccount => {
          return sourceOrganizationAccount.locator === account.locator
            ? {
                ...sourceOrganizationAccount,
                ...accountDetailsRes.accountDetails,
              }
            : sourceOrganizationAccount;
        });

        return updatedArray;
      });
    }
  }

  return <>Test</>;
}
```

My types

```
export type SourceOrganizationAccount = {
  name: string;
  createdOn: number;
  locator: string;
}

export interface StateVariable<T> {
  value: T;
  setValue: (value: T) => void;
}

export interface ImportAccountsState {
    sourceOrganizationAccounts: StateVariable<SourceOrganizationAccount[]>;
}

const ImportAccountsContext = createContext<ImportAccountsState>(
  {} as ImportAccountsState,
);

export const ImportAccountsProvider = ({ children }: props) => {
  const [sourceOrganizationAccounts, setSourceOrganizationAccounts] = useState<
    SourceOrganizationAccount[]
  >([]);

  const resetContext = useCallback(() => {
    setSourceOrganizationAccounts([]);
  }, [
    setSourceOrganizationAccounts,
  ]);

  const initialState: ImportAccountsState = {
    sourceOrganizationAccounts: {
      value: sourceOrganizationAccounts,
      setValue: setSourceOrganizationAccounts,
    }
  };

  return (
    <ImportAccountsContext.Provider value={initialState}>
      {children}
    </ImportAccountsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useImportAccountsContext = () => {
  return useContext<ImportAccountsState>(ImportAccountsContext);
};
```

Comment: @aleksxor It's actually `ImportAccountsState`. I've tried to rename the names to keep it shorter and missed that one. `ImportAccountsState` is an interface at the very top of the types code block.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you check thoroughly your `StateVariable<T>` type you may notice that `setValue` field of that type has signature:

```ts
setValue: (value: T) => void
```

While you're trying to feed it instead of a value of type `T` the value (function) of type: `(prevState: T) => T`.

To match your function implementation the type `StateVariable` should be defined as:

```ts
interface StateVariable<T> {
  value: T;
  setValue: (cb: (value: T) => T) => void;
}
```

React exposes special helper types for typing `useState` dispatch functions: `Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>` so you may write it also as:

```ts
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

interface StateVariable<T> {
  value: T
  setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Any idea why I couldn't use this union `setValue: (value: T) => void | ((cb: (value: T) => T) => void);`? I was experiencing the same TypeScript error.

Comment: I believe you think you're declaring a _union_ of _functions_ but __in fact__ you're declaring a function accepting a value `T` and returning __either__ a `void` __or__ a function accepting a callback and returning a void.
But declaring it as `setValue: ((value: T) => void) | ((cb: (value: T) => T) => void)` wouldn't help. Due to contravariant nature of function arguments the argument such a function would accept should've been of type `(T & (value: T) => T)`.

Comment: This is the solution if react says: ```Argument of type '(count: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.``` and ```Did you mean to call this expression?``` when setting a state with previous value callback.

Comment: To elaborate on what @AkshayKNair was saying, the `SetStateAction<>` inside `Dispatch` is what makes the TypeScript error go away. Normally the `setValue` doesn't need the `SetStateAction` unless you're using `prevState`.